# inserting content into an html layout included in a jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have created an html layout using css for my website.this layout is included in my jsp file using the  action.
My problem is that when i try to put content in my layout's content section it gets shifted outside of the layout and not on it as required.this is the first time i'm using jsp so any help would be great!

below is my code:

```css
.header{
background-color: crimson;
height: 15%;
}

.logo{
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-top: 20px;
width: 21%;
color: black;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 80px;
border: ridge;
border-color: black;
border-width: thick;
}

.footer{
height: 2%;
text-align: center;
}

.body{
padding-top: 15%;
height: 400px;
}

.page{
 background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layoutstyle.css">
</head>
<div class="page">
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
Bookie<small style="font-size: 30px">.com</small>
</div>
</div>
<div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
copyright @abc
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <jsp:include page="layout.html"/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>LogIn</title>
</head>

<div class="body">
hi
</div>
</html>
```

please help!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you labelled which file is which

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any JSP code in any of these files. JSP is Java code enclosed within `<%` and `%>` tags. It sounds like the issue you are having with the content being shifted might be a CSS problem.